# Generate list of shape in Lisp

Tags: linked-list, random, lisp

I quickly created this function in Lisp that resembles

`numpy.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='I')`

The goal is simply to have a function that creates a list of random integers between `low` and `high` and that the list has a certain `shape`. I did not add the ability to choose the `dtype` as well, but this would be a possibility.

My function for doing this is the following:

```
(defun randint (&key (start 0) end (shape '(1)))
  (if (> (length shape) 3)
    (error "Shape can be maximally 3 long")
  (loop for i from 1 upto (first shape)
        if (not (null (rest shape)))
        collect (loop for j from 1 upto (first (rest shape))
                      if (not (null (rest (rest shape))))
                      collect (loop for k from 1 upto (first (rest (rest shape)))
                                    collect (+ start (random (+ 1 (- end start)))))
                      else
                      collect (+ start (random (+ 1 (- end start)))))
        else
        collect (+ start (random (+ 1 (- end start)))))))
```

Is there a more concise or more elegant way of writing this in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I find the structure of the program quite complicated and difficult to read and understand. I think that the reason for this is that the program structure is patterned on the `shape` parameter, whose limitation to three elements is, in my opinion, rather arbitrary.

Why do not eliminate such limitation, and make the function more similar to the original numpy one, in which `shape` can be any list, even an empty list?

The elimination of this restriction could seem to complicate the problem, but instead it simplifies the function if we use a recursive approach on the structure of `shape`:

1. if `shape` is empty, then generate a single random number
2. if `shape` is a list, get the first element, which is a number n, apply n times the function to the rest of the shape and collect the result in a list.

In this way the function is greatly simplified:

```
(defun randint (&key (start 0) (end (1+ start)) (shape '()))
  (if (null shape)
      (+ start (random end))
      (loop as i below (car shape) collect (randint :start start :end end :shape (cdr shape)))))
```

Finally, I don't like the fact that a function has a key parameter which, if omitted, causes an error (`end`). So I would prefer to give it an optional value (for instance `start + 1`). Finally, to complete the similarity with the original function, I think we can default the shape parameter to the empty list, so that the call `(randint :start n :end m)` produce a single integer in the range specified.

Comment: I think this is very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

The seems to be no reason to use [lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_ab.htm) as opposed to [arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_.htm) here.
I would use [multidimensional arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_aacb.htm) instead:

```
(defun random-array (dimensions limit)
  (let ((ret (make-array dimensions)))
    (dotimes (pos (array-total-size ret) ret)
      (setf (row-major-aref ret pos)
            (random limit)))))
(random-array '(2 3 4) 100)
==> #3A(((26 28 3 72) (49 92 34 71) (3 96 76 38))
        ((95 97 60 84) (62 26 36 95) (83 99 12 81)))
```

Please see

- [`make-array`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ar.htm)
- [`array-total-size`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_tot.htm)
- [`row-major-aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_row_ma.htm)
- [`random`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_random.htm)

PS. Note that your function would fail in `(- end start)` if you do not pass `end`.